# mvc 5 dropdownlist Multiple lookup value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

So I have a page where I enter employee details and also select an employee form DropdownList to whom it will report to. My table Employees can have Fields like EmpGuid ,EmpName, EmpParentGuid , Department, Age etc. So basically EmpParentGuid is supervisor to whom EmpGuid reports to.

Below is code for dropdownlist

Controller code

```
ViewBag.EmpParentGuid = new SelectList(db.Employees.ToList(), "EmpGuid ", "EmpName", Employees.EmpParentGuid );
```

View Code

```
 @Html.DropDownList("EmpParentGuid", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

So based on selected EmpParentGuid I can get  its "EmpName" value. Now how can I get other field values and probably display in label next to DropdownList. 
Also how can I get the same during post. Because I want to update few hidden fields based on selected EmpParentGuid. Thanks.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use javascript/jquery to handle the `.change()` event of the dropdownlist and use ajax to call a server method (passing the selected value) and return the additional details and update the DOM

Comment: oh!.... so no easy way to pass whole list and then get selected row values : (

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke. how about if I don't need to display in label. But get values when whole page is posted.

Comment: When your submit, you know the selected employee (its the value of property `EmpParentGuid` - but do you really have a property in your model named `EmpParentGuid`?) so you can just look up the database to get all the properties of the selected employee. And you really need to stop using `DropDownList()` and start using view models and the strongly typed `DropDownListFor()` method.

Comment: Thanks again @StephenMuecke. Yes I do have EmpParentGuid  in my Model because It's part of table column. I will work on your suggestion for looking up in database.

Answer (score 0):

HTML PAGE:

```
@Html.ListBox("EmpParentGuid", null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "ElementID", @class = "form-control" })
```

Add script for change event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ElementID").change(function () {
        var Id = $("#ElementID").val();
        $("#IdOfPartialViewHolder").load('@(Url.Action("ActionName", "Controller", null, Request.Url.Scheme))?EmpParentGuid=' + Id);
    });
});
```

HTML FOR Partial VIEW:

```
<div id="IdOfPartialViewHolder" class="h6 ">
    @Html.Partial("_YourPartialView", Model)
</div>
```

Partial View:

```
@model YourProject.Models.EmployeesViewModel   
<div>    
   Text1: &nbsp @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.YourModelColumn1)    <br />
   Text2: &nbsp @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.YourModelColumn2) 
                                            ... YourModelColumn5        
</div>
```

C# CODE how to update partial view:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ActionName(string EmpParentGuid)
    {
        Guid IDtemp = new Guid(EmpParentGuid);
        EmployeesViewModel model = new EmployeesViewModel();
        Employees E = new Employees();
        E = await db.Employees .FindAsync(IDtemp);
        model.YourModelColumn1 = E.YourModelColumn1;
        model.YourModelColumn2 = E.YourModelColumn2;
        return PartialView("_YourPartialView", model);
    }
```

Maybe exist better solution, but this working for me...

If you will submit HTML FORM

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    YOUR HTML
}
```

Comment: If you will have some problem with ajax add this:  $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    });